# Qlikview how to get all rows

Tags: javascript, qlikview

In my app Qlikview is loading a table with some rows, it loads more rows when I scroll down the table. The issue is how can I get all the rows without scrolling down? On click of a button I need to download all rows. here is my code

```
var firstBody = Qv.GetCurrentDocument();
firstBody.GetObject('doc123', function () {                            
    var d = this.Data.Rows;    //here getting only top rows which loads on page load.
});
```

Ok I found this way, but in such approach I need to load the document 2 times.

```
var firstBody = Qv.GetCurrentDocument();
    firstBody.GetObject('doc123', function () {  
        var totalSizeY = this.Data.TotalSize.y;
        this.Data.SetPagesizeY(totalSizeY); 
        firstBody.GetObject('doc123', function () {                         
            var d = this.Data.Rows;    //now here are all rows
        });
    });
```